# Why is my scanner skipping every other user input when I print my StringBuilder?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String welcomeMsg = "Enter inputs. Leave blank and hit Enter when done."

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(welcomeMsg);

    StringBuilder attendees = new StringBuilder();

    while (!sc.nextLine().equals("")){
        attendees.append(sc.nextLine());
    }
    System.out.println(attendees);
}
```

The scanner seems to be working fine. I can input say, a then hit enter. Hit b and hit enter. And so on through h. Then, leaving the line blank and hitting enter, it gets to work.
But the output is:

bdfh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you read the line twice, once here `while (!sc.nextLine().equals(""))` then again here `attendees.append(sc.nextLine());` which causes the first line read each loop cycle to be skipped.

To fix this simply read once using a temporary string. Here is one option:

```
//Read to temporary string
String line = sc.nextLine();

//Now process the string
while (!line.equals("")){
    attendees.append(line );

    //read the next line for the next loop cycle
    line = sc.nextLine()
}
```

Comment: Beautiful. What a headache and a lesson I will never forget. It's so simple but after hours of staring at this screen, I don't think I would have ever figured that out on purpose. Great Explanation. Many thanks. Upvoted. (would have upvoted but I'm too new)